# Issues in Convergence of Sequential minimal optimization for SVM

Tags: machine-learning, smo, classification, svm, convex-optimization

I have been working on Support Vector Machine for about 2 months now. I have coded SVM myself and for the optimization problem of SVM, I have used Sequential Minimal Optimization(SMO) by Dr. John Platt.

Right now I am in the phase where I am going to grid search to find optimal C value for my dataset. ( Please find details of my project application and dataset details here [SVM Classification - minimum number of input sets for each class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284059/svm-classification-minimum-number-of-input-sets-for-each-class))

I have successfully checked my custom implemented SVM`s accuracy for C values ranging from 2^0 to 2^6. But now I am having some issues regarding the convergence of the SMO for C> 128.
Like I have tried to find the alpha values for C=128 and it is taking long time before it actually converges and successfully gives alpha values.

Time taken for the SMO to converge is about 5 hours for C=100. This huge I think ( because SMO is supposed to be fast. ) though I`m getting good accuracy?
I am screwed right not because I can not test the accuracy for higher values of C.

I am actually displaying number of alphas changed in every pass of SMO and getting 10, 13, 8... alphas changing continuously. The KKT conditions assures convergence so what is so weird happening here?

Please note that my implementation is working fine for C<=100 with good accuracy though the execution time is long.

Please give me inputs on this issue.

Thank You and Cheers.

Comment: I think I asked this before for one of your other questions, but why aren't you using an existing SVM package?

Comment: I think I mentioned the reason why I am implementing SVM myself. I am bachelor of Technology student and my institute won`t allow me to use any of the ready-to-use implementations of SVM.
Frankly because if I use any I will not be able learn most of the things concerning SVM.

Comment: It would be worthy to compare it with your implementation though. If libsvm is slow with this too, you aren't doing anything wrong most certainly.

Answer (score 5):

For most SVM implementations, training time can increase dramatically with larger values of C. To get a sense of how training time in a reasonably good implementation of SMO scales with C, take a look at the log-scale line for libSVM in the graph below.

**SVM training time vs. C** - From Sentelle et al.'s [A Fast Revised Simplex Method for SVM Training](http://figment.cse.usf.edu/~sfefilat/data/papers/WeAT9.49.pdf).

[alt text http://dmcer.net/StackOverflowImages/svm_scaling.png](http://figment.cse.usf.edu/~sfefilat/data/papers/WeAT9.49.pdf)

You probably have two easy ways and one not so easy way to make things faster.

Let's start with the easy stuff. First, you could try **loosening your convergence criteria**. A strict criteria like epsilon = 0.001 will take much longer to train, while typically resulting in a model that is no better than a looser criteria like epsilon = 0.01. Second, you should try to **profile your code** to see if there are any obvious bottlenecks.

The not so easy fix, would be to switch to a different optimization algorithm (e.g., SVM-RSQP from Sentelle et al.'s paper above). But, if you have a working implementation of SMO, you should probably only really do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want complete convergence, especially if C is large, it takes a very long time.You can consider defining a large stop criterion, and give the maximum number of iterations, the default in Libsvm is 1000000, if the number of iterations is more, the time will multiply, but the loss is not worth the cost, but the result may not fully meet the KKT condition, some support vectors are in the band, non-support vectors are out of the band, but the error is small and acceptable.In my opinion, it is recommended to use other quadratic programming algorithms instead of SMO algorithm if the accuracy is higher